# Как сделать искривлённую горизонтальную линию в виде шторки (ᴗᴗᴗᴗᴗ)

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

### Вопрос

Как сделать разделительную линию в виде шторки состоящей из полукругов расположенных горизонтально?
Есть ли элегантное решение не используя JS?

---

Что было предпринято из попыток:

#### Вариант 1

Из заголовка вопроса очевидно, что проще всего её сделать текстом используя [Latin Small Letter Bottom Half O](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+1D17).
Но, так как подобная шторка подразумевается как графический элемент, а не текст, это не очень хорошее решение. Мы ведь не можем выделить `<hr>` при просмотре страницы.

```html
<div>ᴗᴗᴗᴗᴗ</div>
```

Но так её можно будет выделить, что нежелательно для графического элемента, и она насолит в SEO.

#### Вариант 2

С этим вариантом дела обстоят более чудесно, используется CSS, но если кружков в шторке необходимо сделать 20+, то html разметка выглядит ужасно, т.к. один и тот же `<div>` повторяется множество раз.

```css
 .circle {
    width: 20px;
    height: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    border: 3px solid black;
    border-top: 0;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
  <div class="circle"></div>
</div>
```

#### Прочее

Можно, конечно, использовать изображение, но под такой простой элемент это слишком.
Также смотрел в сторону [стилистики `<hr>`](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-style-a-horizontal-line.html), но в ней за рамки прямой линии не выйти. Можно её [искривить](https://codepen.io/hazmi/pen/VwKreoq), но это уже с использованием JS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Суть подобного графического оформления - узор, который можно легко нарисовать с помощью градиентов:

```css
.curtain {
  height: 10px;
  border: none;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at top center, #0000 0 calc(50% - 5px), #000 calc(50% - 4px) calc(50% - 2px), #0000 calc(50% - 1px)) repeat-x 50% 0 / 20px 20px;
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0000, #000 15px calc(100% - 15px), #0000);
  mask-image: linear-gradient(to right, #0000, #000 15px calc(100% - 15px), #0000);
}
```

```html
<hr class="curtain">
```

Comment: В действительности элегантно! Не очень нравится затухание по краям, но понимаю зачем оно. Если его убрать, то края будут обрезаны, для переменной ширины очень хорошее решение. Ну а отрисовать без него и без обрезания, я так понимаю, можно на фиксированной ширине, если поиграться с размерами.

Comment: @DiMithras, абсолютно верно - если задавать кратную ширину, то можно отказаться от затухания.